# How to query posts in Wordpress by ID range?

Tags: wordpress, where-clause

I want to query posts in Wordpress by ID range. For example query posts that have ID between 9 - 40. Or get posts that have IDs greater than 9 (ID>9).
How can I specified this type of query in Wordpress?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Such an approach implies you would have any kind of control/ knowledge over how those IDs are generated. But WordPress stores posts/ pages/ media/ post-revisions in wp_posts so looking for all posts with id>9 may yield images or revisions as well as posts. The numbering sequence would be offset by that so you can't depend of these IDs to maintain a certain relation between each other. That leaves you with very narrow use cases in which this feature could be needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment Mihai. I want to get posts in realtime and for that I fetch posts from last ID that loaded in loop. Another approach for realtime fetching, I think may be using date and time. In query I mention that post type to be 'post' so it never gets other types like image or video, etc.
Do I'm in wrong way? Please note me that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of using `polling` to "catch" the new posts after they have been inserted why don't you use the WordPress hooks api? I think there is a hook that is specifically tied to the moment when a post has been inserted.

Comment: And how it works? Can you please explain more? I didn't work with hooks.

Comment: What @Sheikh said is an example of usage of hooks but it uses your ideea of polling for the latest posts. In my idea, you create a function `on_save_post` and "hook it" to the save_post action `add_action( 'save_post', 'on_save_post');` That way when any WordPress user creates a new post, your function `on_save_post` gets executed. From that function you can write data to a log table and read it with any process that needs that data.

Comment: Thank you Mihai, you showed the better way. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this filter, just paste this function in your functions.php

```
function filter_by_id($where = '')
{
    $where .= " AND ID > 50 AND ID < 100";
    return $where;
}
```

And in your template file

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_by_id');
$args=array(...);
$my_post = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $my_post->have_posts() ) : $my_post->the_post();
    // your code
endwhile;
remove_filter('posts_where' , 'filter_by_id');
```

Comment: Thank you Sheikh, very nice. I just implemented that and it works.
But I want to add ranges dynamically so I must use extra parameters in add filter. I got idea from your answer. Thanks a lot Sheikh.